# Adjust Table View Cell custom view constraint after image loaded from url

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, imageview, uitableviewautomaticdimension

In my application, I have a `uitableview` whose cell height is measured by `autolayout` `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

The cell contains an image, whose height is adjusted by a `NSLayoutconstraint` outlet connected to cell.

Image is loaded from a URL. Sometimes the URL will returns "No Image". At this point, I need to change the height constraint to zero.

If an image is available I need to adjust the constraint with a height of 200. The image is loaded from background thread.

But, when I try to update the constraint after image is loaded from web, it doesn't work.

Please suggest a method to resolve the situation.